# EF 4.1 code-first: How to design and map these entities?

Tags: entity-framework-4.1, ef-code-first, entity-relationship, navigation-properties

I have 3 entities: `Member`, `AuthenticationToken`, and `Email`.

1. Each `Member` may has *many* `AuthenticationTokens`
2. Each `AuthenticationToken` may has *one or zero* `Email`
3. Each `Member` may has *zero or one* `PrimaryEmail` (from `Emails` table). *Really the `PrimaryEmail` is one of the  `AuthenticationToken`s's associated  `Email`*

So I have:

```
public class Member {
    public int MemberId { get; set; }
    public int? PrimaryEmailId { get; set; }
    public virtual Email PrimaryEmail { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<AuthenticationToken> AuthenticationTokens { get; set; }
}

public class AuthenticationToken {
    public int AuthenticationTokenId { get; set; }
    public int MemberId { get; set; }
    public virtual Member Member { get; set; }
    public virtual Email Email { get; set; }
}

public class Email {
    public int EmailId { get; set; } // is same as AuthenticationTokenId that the email associated with it
}
```

With design I explained above, I can add Member and AuthenticationToken, but when I want to attach a Email to a Member or AuthenticationToken (or both) I give this error:

> The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint etc.

Is this design correct??? 
How can I design my tables (and entities) to achieve my purpose? 
And how can I map my entities in code-first? Have you any idea please?

[image]

Comment: Is Id in Email configured to not be autogenerated?

Comment: Yes it is! Do you think this design is correct?

Comment: Did you also configure EF that EmailId is not autogenerated?

Comment: Use SQL profiler and check what insert command does it use when inserting email.

Answer (score 1):

I personally use the fluent API in EF 4.1 to configure all of my entities when I don't feel the default conventions will understand me, so I will answer using the fluent API.

Here is how I would set up the models:

```
public class Member
{
    public Member()
    {
        AuthenticationTokens = new List<AuthenticationToken>();
    }

    public int MemberId { get; set; }

    public virtual Email PrimaryEmail { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<AuthenticationToken> AuthenticationTokens { get; set; }
}

public class AuthenticationToken
{
    public int AuthenticationTokenId { get; set; }

    public virtual Email Email { get; set; }
}

public class Email
{
    public int EmailId { get; set; }
}
```

And this is my context and fluent configuration:

```
public class ExampleApplicationContext : DbContext
{
    public ExampleApplicationContext()
        : base("ExampleApplicationConnection")
    {

    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        // No cascade on delete because the primary email may be held by an authentication token.
        modelBuilder.Entity<Member>()
            .HasOptional(x => x.PrimaryEmail)
            .WithOptionalDependent()
            .Map(x =>
            {
                x.MapKey("EmailId");
            })
            .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);

        // Cascade on delete because an authentication token not associated with a Member makes no sense.
        modelBuilder.Entity<Member>()
            .HasMany(x => x.AuthenticationTokens)
            .WithRequired()
            .Map(x =>
            {
                x.MapKey("MemberId");
            })
            .WillCascadeOnDelete();

        // No cascade on delete because an email may be held by a Member.
        modelBuilder.Entity<AuthenticationToken>()
            .HasOptional(x => x.Email)
            .WithOptionalDependent()
            .Map(x =>
            {
                x.MapKey("EmailId");
            })
            .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
    }

    public DbSet<Member> Members { get; set; }
}
```

I will do my best here to explain my reasoning as to why I designed it like this. First of all, it appears that in your model `Member` should be the root aggregate (the boss of the other entities). What I mean is an `Authentication Token` makes no sense unless it belongs to a specific `Member`. An `Email` also makes no sense alone unless it either belongs to a `Member` or belongs to an `AuthenticationToken`. For this reason `AuthenticationToken` does not have a property to find out what `Member` it is attached to (to find this out you first need a `Member` and than just look at its collection). Essentially, everything revolves around a `Member` object. Without a `Member` an `AuthenticationToken` cannot be created. And without a `Member` or an `AuthenticationToken` an `Email` cannot be created.

I'm not entirely sure how comfortable you are with the fluent API in EF 4.1, so if you have any questions leave a comment and I will do my best to answer them. I have also included a small sample application that I used to build and verify the model I presented above. If you want to run the program (it is a small Console app) you just have to modify the connection string in App.config to point to your instance of SQL Server.

One thing that concerns me is the fact that `Email` can belong to both a `Member` and an `AuthenticationToken`. My concern comes from the fact that I had to setup some interesting cascade deletes. I don't know all of your requirements, however, and this setup appears to work just fine so that may not be an issue.

[Example Console Application](http://www.mediafire.com/?7t4a8qt2e889l1y)

Comment: Just realized this is a rather old question. Hopefully it will help someone though.